# TOR BUG,Tor dropping SSH tunnel to hidden SSH service

Tags: onion-services, socks, network-configuration, ssh, tunnel

I have multiple hidden services which are SSH servers.

They do give unstable connections, and drop out all the time (after a couple seconds).
Sometimes with a SOCKS error 1 or with 
packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe

A couple specifics

- I use openssh as the server
- HidServAuth is properly configured on all client
- I use netcat-openbsd to connect to the socks 5 proxy (configured
  through ProxyCommand)
- Compression Yes in the client .ssh/config file

Anybody any suggestions to overcome this kind of behavior?

EDIT: I tried every ProxyCommand, but I feel like it is the Socks proxy of tor (or tor itself) that drops the packet or stops working.
I'm running in a chroot, can this make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the server was hosted on a non-standard ssh port (2022).
Solutions:

- Use the LongLivedPorts  to add your port in your torrc and make more stable connections for certain ports
- If the ssh server is a hidden service, 22 127.0.0.1:2022 in your torrc will redirect this to a port in LongLivedPorts

Answer (score 0):

Well, post your client and service's config file to clarify it. The step-by-step checklist answers are:

- I'm using OpenSSH as a server too, also tried WinSSHD - works fine too
- Haven't used it, I'm using a bit different security scheme
- Please post your ProxyCommand value - maybe here is the problem. I've used either a PRoxyCommand or TransPort+firewall+NAT - no problems so far
- It does matter *only* if you're using windows clients like PuTTY - sometimes they will behave exactly like this. BitwiseSSH works perfect with compression under windows, PuTTY does have a problem here. In case of Linux or Unix(FreeBSD, Solaris) clients I've tried - no problem with compression level at all

So post your configs and we will try to figure it out deeper.

UPDATE: Chroot should cause no problem at all, it either breaks all things apart or it just works. Do you use keepalives in SSH **and** SSHD configs?

UPDATE#2: Then we'll try a different setup:

add this on tor installations client side:

```
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 127.0.0.1
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 127.0.0.1
```

and divert all the traffic to this subnet into 127.0.0.1 port 9040 via your nat/firewall. Remove the ProxyCommand from ssh configs and use 127.0.0.1:53 as a resolver dns. After that try connecting this way

Comment: I used ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p, This was with netcat-openbsd. Could Socks5 Be the problem?

Comment: From testing with socat (socks4), SOCKS protocol version can be excluded.

Comment: Another thing, If I have multiple sessions open, they all close at the same time, I think it has to do with tor, or the SOCKS port

Comment: No neither, but when I researched more in the tor log, I find this error https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19711 . It is an active bug

Comment: hmm, not really - I used to use SOCKS for quite a long time. Add keepalives and add port 22 to LongLivingPorts - let's see what's happen

Comment: WIll do, LongLivingPorts on hidden_service or on client tor instance?

Comment: on both sides - so as the keepalives. I'm using 15-30 seconds for keepalives

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it with all my servers now, and I just realized something, I'm using a non-standard port (2022) for the ssh, LongLivedPorts defaults with ports like 21,22,... To be continued

Comment: then add your port to that list. I've used quite an assortment of non-standart ports, and it was never faulty

Comment: On both sides did keepalives, reloaded services, rebooted, changed ssh server to port 22, no change

Comment: updated my answer - let's try a TransPort - it gives a better speed and connection stability

Comment: No it doesn't, Alexey. Stop making stuff up to try and sound clever.

Comment: @canonizingironize the moments we're passing now are the problem-makers in some cases, I'm not googling and pasting - the things I'm recommending here are tested by me. I currently have 4 HS'es with OpenSSH and have no problem in accessing them. So yes - we will fire it up and this will work, this way or another

Comment: Ok, I tried removing Tor, start blank, have SSH servers on port 22, and know it has been a while since it deconnected (1 hour vs 30 seconds before). Maybe it used the old circuit with without the LongLivedPorts option. If this doesn't work... What should I try next?

Comment: SOLVED! I made a second ssh server on 2022 and connected from the same client, that one died after 20 seconds, but the other connection stayed up! The LongLivedPorts is a good tip, I'll just redirect my sshd server on port 22 in the torrc config

Comment: have you tried new torrc without fully restarting Tor?

Comment: Fully removed tor from box, installed again, reconfigured the torrc with basic hidden service on port 22. Done ;) I was wise enough to restart the service after making changes to the torrc (if that is what you where helpfully saying)

Comment: Can I know what the other security scheme is (which you mentioned) I think HidServAuth is quite clunky

Comment: yes I was talking about not sending SIGHUP but restarting the Tor completely.

Comment: I'm using the ssh keys and they're enforced, so it makes it a bit different, but I don't actually care if someone will see the non-standart SSH port opened. the keys I've put on the servers are offline-generated and inserted in the HS boxes physically by me, so it seems to be secure enough.

Comment: I also use ssh keys (rsa), Ok I thought I was missing something, Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome! Feel free to ask questions - I'm glad to help!

Comment: And it's back again, It really depends from time to time I guess...

Comment: "the things I'm recommending here are tested by me" cool lets see your data showing why "TransPort...gives a better speed and connection stability" and your technical analysis showing that too, since you're just making stuff up to sound impressive as usual this time.

Comment: @canonizingironize what kind of data do you need?

Comment: Give us the technical rundown of why it's faster.

Comment: the reason's root is in task priority: TransPort routing is performed by kernel, so - giving even a highest priority to the Tor process(which I did) does not leverage the rt priority of the kernel and it's netfilter modules in particular. The overhead in speed is not so high, but stability is greatly impacted: try to make 100+ TCP pipes through Tor in both ways and see the real difference. The difference is best observable on ARM CPU's of a middle grade: one of the best examples is Raspberry Pi B, a single-core one with a big SD card. On x86 it does show up too, but not in such a form